# Java - Hibernate calling a MySql Stored Procedure - Warning Message

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a Java project where I call a stored procedure using hibernate.

Here is sample code I am using

```
  public String findCloudName(Long cloudId) {
        LOG.info("Entered findCloudName Method - cloudId:{}", cloudId);

        String cloudName  = null;
        ProcedureCall  procedureCall = currentSession().createStoredProcedureCall("p_getCloudDetails");
        procedureCall.registerParameter( "cloudId", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN ).bindValue( cloudId );
        procedureCall.registerParameter( "cloudName", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT );

        ProcedureOutputs  outputs = procedureCall.getOutputs();

        cloudName = (String) outputs.getOutputParameterValue( "cloudName" );

        LOG.info("Exiting findCloudName Method - cloudName:{}", cloudName);
        return cloudName; 
    }
```

This works fine and results the expected results.
However It leaves the following message in my logs

```
[WARN] [320]org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl[prepareForNamedParameters]  - HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.
```

I was looking through websites and the source code of hibernate to try and figure out how to get rid of this warning

Any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to the correction of [HHH-8740](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8740) :

> In some cases, the database metadata is incorrect (i.e., says something is not supported, when it actually is supported). In this case it would be preferable to simply log a warning. If it turns out that named parameters really are not supported, then a SQLException will be thrown later when the named parameter is bound to the SQL statement.

So, the warning warn you from calling a method that queries metadata on named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    
    System.out.println("Enter Id:");
    int id=sc.nextInt();
    
    StoredProcedureQuery query=session.createStoredProcedureCall("Delete",Employee.class);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    
    query.setParameter("id",sc.nextInt());
    query.executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
```

Comment: org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl prepareForNamedParameters
WARN: HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.
this error shows me

Comment: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `namednative_crud`.`Delete` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `namednative_crud`.`Delete` (IN eid int)
BEGIN
          delete from Employee where id=eid;
End

Comment: this is the query i written and then shows above error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).